# ASP.NET Query associated with three tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm not very much aware of DB and Query

i've three tables

EMP(Contains details)  Junction(contains ID of EMP table and ID of skill table) skill(contains skills)

here junction table is providing many to many relationship to emp and skill, i.e., one emp can have many skills and one skill can have many emp.
now the problem is i've to populate a GridView with E_details by Selecting the the skills from the skiltable.
can you tell me a example to make a select query for EMP table by selecting particular for which emp ID and Skill ID are present in Junction Table...

Thanks

Comment: Do you know which technology you are using to access your database?  ADO.NET (`System.Data.SqlClient` classes), Entity Framework (`System.Data.Entity` classes) or something else?

Comment: Are you saying the user is going to select a skill, and you need to display the employees that have that skill?

Comment: yes i'm going to display emp details associated to the skill selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ADO.NET you could write it as follows:

```
string query = @"SELECT e.*
                 FROM EMP e
                 INNER JOIN Junction j ON e.ID = j.empID
                 WHERE j.skillID = @SkillID";

int skillID = 5;

using (var conn = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
{
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SkillID", skillID);

        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int id = (int)reader["ID"];
                int name = (string)reader["Name"];

                // etc.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In ASP.NET just feed the `skillID` variable as a query string variable to the request.  And project each column read into a model you can use to populate inside a GridView.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to modify this based on your table structure...but I'm going to assume you have emp.id and skill.id as primary keys in your tables.

It would be along the lines of:

```
Select EMP.*, Skill.*
FROM emp
INNER JOIN Junction ON emp.ID=junction.empID
inner join Skill ON skill.id = junction.skillID
```

You would need to change this based on the columns in your tables, and the values you want to retrieve from them...